# How to find actual value of integers participated in sum operation

Tags: math

I have integers with power 2^n where n = 0 to 5
Lets say I have integers such as 2^0=1, 2^1=2, 2^2=4, 2^3=8, 2^4=16, 2^5=32

now when I get sum 42 of some integers belonging to above mentioned integer (the integers
cannot repeat itself i.e 2+2 cannot be done )

How can I obtain the actual integers participated in calculating the value 42 which is 32,8,2

Comment: Check "Change-making problem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format your number as binary notation, in this case for 42 it would be `101010`, from the notation get the index of `1` (start from 0) , it's `5,3,1`. and then you have `2^5 + 2^3 + 2^1`